# Read/Write inifiles with boost::{program_options,property_tree}

Tags: c++, boost, boost-program-options, boost-propertytree

Utilizing boost, I would like to

1. read options from an inifile, abort if an unknown option is encountered in the inifile and
2. save them later in another inifile.

The first part can be done with boost::program_options:

```
try{
    inifile_options.add_options()
    ("ops1.i0", po::value<int>(&p.nx)->default_value(1), "test integer")
    ;

    po::variables_map vm;
    po::store(po::parse_config_file(pthfnini, inifile_options), vm);
    po::notify(vm);
}   
catch(exception& e){
    cerr << "error: " << e.what() << "\n";
    errorflag=1;
}
```

To the best of my knowledge writing an inifile is not possible with boost::program_options, but boost::property_tree works:

```
pt::ptree iniPropTree;
pt::ini_parser::write_ini("./used0.ini",iniPropTree);
```

Now the question is how can I translate the data stored in the po::variables_map to pt::ptree?

Reading the boost documentation leaves me with the impression that this is not possible. Is the following the only viable way?

```
iniPropTree.put<int>("ops1.i0",vm["ops1.i0"].as<int>();
```

It introduces quite a bit of redundancy for my taste. However, reading data into a property tree from the beginning does not seem to support checking for undefined/misspelled options.

Alternatively,is it possible to iterate over the contents of variables_map and somehow infer the corresponding datatype of each element?

The full code is here:

```
/*
 * g++ iniOps_test.cpp -Wall -std=c++11 -O3 -lboost_system -lboost_program_options -o iniOps_test.exe
 * 
 */

// C++11 & Boost libraries
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>            // po::options_description, po::variables_map, ...
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>        // pt::ptree
#include <boost/property_tree/ini_parser.hpp>   // write_ini()
#include <iostream>                             // cout
#include <fstream>                              // ofstream, ifstream


// namespaces
namespace po = boost::program_options;
namespace pt = boost::property_tree;
using namespace std;


struct params{
    std::string inipthfn;
    int i0;
};


void read_inifile(params &p, po::variables_map &vm){

    // initialize variables
    int errorflag=0;
    std::ifstream pthfnini("./testini.ini");
    po::options_description inifile_options("Allowed inifile options");

    try{
        inifile_options.add_options()
        ("ops1.i0", po::value<int>(&p.i0)->default_value(1), "test integer")
        ;

        ;
        po::store(po::parse_config_file(pthfnini, inifile_options), vm);
        po::notify(vm);
    }
    catch(exception& e){
        cerr << "error: " << e.what() << "\n";
        errorflag=1;
    }

    pthfnini.close();
    if(errorflag){ std::cout<<"--- program shutdown due to error in read_inifile ---"<<std::endl; exit(1); }
}


int main(){

    params p;
    po::variables_map vm;
    pt::ptree iniPropTree;

    read_inifile(p,vm);                                     // get options from inifile

    // ??? conversion from vm -> pt ???

    pt::ini_parser::write_ini("./used0.ini",iniPropTree);   // save options to used.ini
    cout << p.i0 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The contents of the inifile "testini.ini" are:

```
[ops1]
i0=2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After giving this problem some more time, I found a suitable compact solution:

The key is to write a function that translates entries from the variables_map to the propTree depending on their datatype (thx to sehe for putting me on the right track):

```
void translate_variables_map_to_ptree(po::variables_map &vm, pt::ptree &propTree){

    for(po::variables_map::iterator it=vm.begin(); it!=vm.end(); it++){
        if( it->second.value().type() == typeid(int) ){ propTree.put<int>(it->first,vm[it->first].as<int>()); }
        else if( it->second.value().type() == typeid(float) ){ propTree.put<float>(it->first,vm[it->first].as<float>()); }
        else if( it->second.value().type() == typeid(double) ){ propTree.put<double>(it->first,vm[it->first].as<double>()); }
        else if( it->second.value().type() == typeid(std::string) ){ propTree.put<std::string>(it->first,vm[it->first].as<std::string>()); }
        else if( it->second.value().type() == typeid(size_t) ){ propTree.put<size_t>(it->first,vm[it->first].as<size_t>()); }
        else{ printf("Error: unknown datatype. Abort!\n"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
    }
}
```

The full working example writes the correct inifile containing all read info:

```
/*
 * g++ iniOps_test.cpp -Wall -std=c++11 -O3 -lboost_system -lboost_program_options -o iniOps_test.exe
 * 
 */

// C++11 & Boost libraries
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>            // po::options_description, po::variables_map, ...
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>        // pt::ptree
#include <boost/property_tree/ini_parser.hpp>   // write_ini()
#include <iostream>                             // cout
#include <fstream>                              // ofstream, ifstream


// namespaces
namespace po = boost::program_options;
namespace pt = boost::property_tree;
using namespace std;


struct params{
    std::string s0;
    int i0;
};


void read_inifile(params &p, po::variables_map &vm){

    // initialize variables
    int errorflag=0;
    std::ifstream pthfnini("./testini.ini");
    po::options_description inifile_options("Allowed inifile options");

    try{
        inifile_options.add_options()
        ("ops1.i0", po::value<int>(&p.i0)->default_value(1), "test integer")
        ("ops1.s0", po::value<std::string>(&p.s0)->default_value("default"), "test string")
        ;

        ;
        po::store(po::parse_config_file(pthfnini, inifile_options), vm);
        po::notify(vm);
    }
    catch(exception& e){
        cerr << "error: " << e.what() << "\n";
        errorflag=1;
    }

    pthfnini.close();
    if(errorflag){ std::cout<<"--- program shutdown due to error in read_inifile ---"<<std::endl; exit(1); }
}

void translate_variables_map_to_ptree(po::variables_map &vm, pt::ptree &propTree){

    for(po::variables_map::iterator it=vm.begin(); it!=vm.end(); it++){
        if( it->second.value().type() == typeid(int) ){ propTree.put<int>(it->first,vm[it->first].as<int>()); }
        else if( it->second.value().type() == typeid(float) ){ propTree.put<float>(it->first,vm[it->first].as<float>()); }
        else if( it->second.value().type() == typeid(double) ){ propTree.put<double>(it->first,vm[it->first].as<double>()); }
        else if( it->second.value().type() == typeid(std::string) ){ propTree.put<std::string>(it->first,vm[it->first].as<std::string>()); }
        else if( it->second.value().type() == typeid(size_t) ){ propTree.put<size_t>(it->first,vm[it->first].as<size_t>()); }
        else{ printf("Error: unknown datatype. Abort!\n"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
    }
}


int main(){

    params p;
    po::variables_map vm;
    pt::ptree iniPropTree;

    read_inifile(p,vm);                                     // get options from inifile
    translate_variables_map_to_ptree(vm,iniPropTree);       // conversion from vm -> pt 
    pt::ini_parser::write_ini("./used0.ini",iniPropTree);   // save options to used.ini

    cout << p.i0 << endl;
    cout << p.s0 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Taking a variables_map vm from reading the commandline, it is also possible to update the values in the property tree (from reading the inifile) with:

```
string opsName = "ops1.i0"; if(vm.count(opsName)) p.i0 = vm[opsName].as<int>();
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a conceptual problem here.

Commandline parameters are inherently textual.

Values in the variables-map aren't. The types used are configured in the value-semantics (part of your options-description).

If all your options have the same type, you can "cheat" and hard-code a conversion:

```
pt::ptree to_ptree(po::variables_map const& vm) {
    pt::ptree tree;
    for (auto& v : vm) {
        if (!v.second.empty() && !v.second.defaulted())
            tree.put(v.first, v.second.as<int>());
    }

    return tree;
}
```

Which saves:

```
[ops1]
i0=1
```

If you need more flexibility, you'd need access to the option  descriptions at the very least. This is not the intended use of the library, and you'll probably run into undocumented parts of the implementation soon.

Answer (score 1):

> However, reading data into a property tree from the beginning does not seem to support checking for undefined/misspelled options

Well. That's not entirely true. You can make your own parse function that adds the logic. Use Property Tree Translators if you want.

Here's an extended example showing three parameters of varying types to be validated:

```
enum class restricted { value1, value2 };

struct params {
    int        i0  = 1;
    restricted r1  = restricted::value2;
    std::string s2 = "some default";
};
```

We will want to have a parse function like this:

```
params read_inifile(std::string filename) {
    params p;
    pt::ptree tree;
    std::ifstream file(filename);

    read_ini(file, tree);
    p.i0 = tree.get("ops1.i0", 1);
    p.r1 = tree.get("ops1.r1", restricted::value2);
    p.s2 = tree.get("ops1.s2", "some default");

    return p;
}
```

### Streamable Types

To translate and validate the enum you merely need to implement the streaming operators:

```
static inline std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, restricted& r) {
    std::string v;
    if (is >> std::ws >> v) {
        if (boost::iequals("value1", v))
            r = restricted::value1;
        else if (boost::iequals("value2", v))
            r = restricted::value2;
        else
            throw std::runtime_error("invalid restricted value");
    }
    return is;
}

static inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, restricted r) {
    switch(r) {
        case restricted::value1: return os << "value1";
        case restricted::value2: return os << "value2";
        default:                 return os << "invalid";
    }
}
```

### Custom Translators

Let's imagine that `i0` need custom validation. In this example, let's REQUIRE it to be an odd number:

```
namespace translators {

    template <typename T>
    struct must_be_odd {
        typedef T internal_type;
        typedef T external_type;

        boost::optional<T> get_value(const std::string& str) const {
            if (str.empty()) return boost::none;

            T v = boost::lexical_cast<T>(str);

            if (v % 2 == 0)
                throw std::runtime_error("value must be odd");

            return boost::make_optional(v);
        }

        boost::optional<std::string> put_value(const T& i0) {
            assert(i0 % 2); // assert that the value was odd
            return boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(i0);
        }
    };

    static const must_be_odd<int> i0;
}
```

Now we can simply supply the translator (here, acting more like a custom validator like Boost Program Options also has them):

```
    p.i0 = tree.get("ops1.i0", 1, translators::i0);
```

> See it **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c4f5099d697260d7)</kbd>**

### Unsupported Options

This is a bit more work. You'll have to iterate the tree checking the resultant paths against a known set. Here's a stab at a reasonably generic implementation of that (which should work correctly with case sensitive trees of any (wide) string type):

```
template <typename Tree, 
         typename Path = typename Tree::path_type,
         typename Key = typename Path::key_type,
         typename Cmp = typename Tree::key_compare>
std::size_t unsupported(Tree const& tree, std::set<Key, Cmp> const& supported, Path prefix = "") {
    if (tree.size()) {
        std::size_t n = 0;
        for (auto& node : tree) {
            Path sub = prefix;
            sub /= node.first;
            n += unsupported(node.second, supported, sub);
        }
        return n;
    } else {
        if (!supported.count(prefix.dump()) && tree.template get_value_optional<std::string>())
            return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
if (auto n = unsupported(tree, {"ops1.i0", "ops1.r1", "ops2.s2"})) {
    throw std::runtime_error(std::to_string(n) + " unsupported options");
}
```

### Full Demo

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/108a74b77be1bf2d)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

enum class restricted { value1, value2 };

static inline std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, restricted& r) {
    std::string v;
    if (is >> std::ws >> v) {
        if (boost::iequals("value1", v))
            r = restricted::value1;
        else if (boost::iequals("value2", v))
            r = restricted::value2;
        else
            throw std::runtime_error("invalid restricted value");
    }
    return is;
}

static inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, restricted r) {
    switch(r) {
        case restricted::value1: return os << "value1";
        case restricted::value2: return os << "value2";
        default:                 return os << "invalid";
    }
}

struct params {
    int        i0  = 1;
    restricted r1  = restricted::value2;
    std::string s2 = "some default";
};

#include <boost/property_tree/ini_parser.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <fstream>
namespace pt = boost::property_tree;

namespace translators {

    template <typename T>
    struct must_be_odd {
        typedef T internal_type;
        typedef T external_type;

        boost::optional<T> get_value(const std::string& str) const {
            if (str.empty()) return boost::none;

            T v = boost::lexical_cast<T>(str);

            if (v % 2 == 0)
                throw std::runtime_error("value must be odd");

            return boost::make_optional(v);
        }

        boost::optional<std::string> put_value(const T& i0) {
            assert(i0 % 2); // assert that the value was odd
            return boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(i0);
        }
    };

    static const must_be_odd<int> i0;
} 

template <typename Tree, 
         typename Path = typename Tree::path_type,
         typename Key = typename Path::key_type,
         typename Cmp = typename Tree::key_compare>
std::size_t unsupported(Tree const& tree, std::set<Key, Cmp> const& supported, Path prefix = "") {
    if (tree.size()) {
        std::size_t n = 0;
        for (auto& node : tree) {
            Path sub = prefix;
            sub /= node.first;
            n += unsupported(node.second, supported, sub);
        }
        return n;
    } else {
        if (!supported.count(prefix.dump()) && tree.template get_value_optional<std::string>())
            return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

params read_inifile(std::string filename) {
    params p;
    try {
        pt::ptree tree;
        std::ifstream file(filename);

        read_ini(file, tree);

        p.i0 = tree.get("ops1.i0", 1, translators::i0);
        p.r1 = tree.get("ops1.r1", restricted::value2);
        p.s2 = tree.get("ops1.s2", "some default");

        if (auto n = unsupported(tree, {"ops1.i0", "ops1.r1", "ops2.s2"})) {
            throw std::runtime_error(std::to_string(n) + " unsupported options");
        }
    } catch (std::exception const& e) {
        std::cerr << "error: " << e.what() << "\n";
        throw std::runtime_error("read_inifile");
    }

    return p;
}

pt::ptree to_ptree(params const& p) {
    pt::ptree tree;

    tree.put("ops1.i0", p.i0, translators::i0);
    tree.put("ops1.r1", p.r1);
    tree.put("ops1.s2", p.s2);

    return tree;
}

int main() {
    params const p = read_inifile("./testini.ini"); // get options from filename
    write_ini("./used0.ini", to_ptree(p)); // save options to used.ini

    std::cout << p.i0 << std::endl;
}
```

For input like

```
[ops1]
i0=17
i99=oops
[oops1]
also=oops
```

Prints

```
error: 2 unsupported options
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  read_inifile
```

And [changing `17` to `18` prints](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b3d5c77cfed1110d):

```
error: value must be odd
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  read_inifile
```

On valid input, `used0.ini` will be written as expected:

```
[ops1]
i0=1
r1=value2
s2=some default
```